# Parser for user defined infix operators

Tags: parsing, language-design, compiler-construction

I am writing an interpreter for a language where functions can be used as operators. However, the functions content will only be known at runtime.

For that I considered two solutions:

- Parsing is done at runtime, using the runtime information on the function
- All user-defined operators use default values for precedence and associativity.

I chose the latter as I see a number of advantages in parsing separately to execution.

Now it comes to implementation and I am interested to see what options there are. My initial thoughts are a shift reduce parser, but I have little experience in constructing parsers.

Example:

```
LHS op RHS : LHS * RHS     /* define a binary operator 'op' */
var : 3                    /* define a variable */
print 5 op var             /* should print 15 */

LHS op RHS : LHS / RHS     /* Re-define op */
print var op var           /* Should print 1 */
```

in the last case, the parser will get from the lexer: " `id` `id` `id` `id` ". Only at runtime do I know that the 'op' id is an operator.

Comment: Why would you need runtime information to do the parsing? Also (perhaps this answers the first question), how do you intend the use of user-defined operators to look (examples)?

Comment: Whether it is an operator or not is the first, as the language is a single-namespace language. I'll update the post with examples on syntax.

Comment: I still don't see the problem. `id id id` is not valid unless it's `LHS op RHS`, right (assuming you didn't define `print` to be a context-sensetive keyword, which would be madness)? So just parse it as such and check at runtime whether there is such an operator defined. What that operator *mean* is an entirely different problem and doesn't have to be decided at parse time (in fact, it's undecidable without running the problem).

Comment: In which case what kind of parser would you recommend. I have read what Ullman had to say about parsers and now I have too many options :P

Comment: Personally, I'd use a pratt parser (http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm, http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/) because I simply love them (they shine at parsing expressions, but are top-down and simple to write by hand - not that I have much experience with other parsers, but they work better than recursive descent and I'm too lazy to really get into one of the parser generators). But I guess most parsers work fine.

Comment: I was planning on writing the parser by hand... So it's the algorithm I'm interested in. Pratts looks interesting and I haven't seen it before so thanks

Comment: @delnan, your approach won't allow to define different alignment and priority rules for different operators.

Comment: @SK-logic: Yes, but if we allow it we're back to approach #1 as in the question (if the definitions should remain truly dynamic, that is). Clearly that's neither desirable nor very practical, and also horrible language design I'd argue. Plus, OP already stated he wants to avoid it. A static, global declaration of associativity and precedence of a specific operator token (regardless of implementation) should be easy enough to allow (especially with a pratt parser).

Comment: @delnan, it is not a "horrible design", it is clean and easy - see how Haskell is doing it, for example. An alternative approach is to have different identifier syntax for possible binary operators of different precedence, something like what OCaml is doing. And, things like Pratt are obviously extremely limited - I personally prefer Packrat, which makes it very easy to use runtime information or extend the parser in compilation time with new rules.

Comment: @SK-logic: The important difference (which makes it a useful idea instead of a maintainer's nightmare) is that in Haskell, associativity and precedence are set in stone at parse time. If we use the same restriction, there's nothing wrong with it and it can be implemented easily (yes, also with pratt parser - but this isn't a parsing algorithm pissing match, so let's leave it at that).

Comment: From what I have seen of Pratt's parser, I think it compares very well to other methods, and I am working on seeing how easy it is to modify. Initial thoughts are that it is not limited at all, but easily extensible. Furthermore, you can make it work so that it executes statements when it can OR form an AST. This leaves the option perfectly open to allow runtime definition of infix operators. However, I must emphasize this is initial tests and so that may change.

Comment: @Mat, take a look at the Katahdin language, to see how extensible Packrat is. I doubt you can do that with Pratt.

Comment: @SK-logic, I don't need it to be THAT extensible in this case. operators are the only feature I intend to let the user redefine. Anything else can have a preprocessor.

Comment: @delnan, please add an answer for Pratt's algorithm, as I would not have found it without you mentioning it and it is most definitely awesome. Pratt is fantastic because: A) It's easy to implement B) It works with executing while parsing or parsing to an AST, C) It's easy in asm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posting the results of the comments, as requested.)

Solution #1 is definitely ugly, complex to implement, and unneeded, I agree. Solution #2 is by far easier to implement and comprehend. You can also allow custom associativity and precedence for operators, as long as those are known statically. The main thing is that these facts are known at parse time.

As for actual parsing, most parsers will work just fine, as any two expression surrounding an id are an application of a custom infix operator (this is less true if you allow custom precedence and associativity, in that case you need an algorithm that allows determine those on a per-operator basis at parse time). Either case, my personal favorite is a "Top Down Operator Precedence Parser", or Pratt parser. I found the following resources (ordered by usefulness to me, YMMV) describe it quite well:

- [Simple Top-Down Parsing in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm)
- [Pratt Parsers: Expression Parsing Made Easy](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/)
- [Top Down Operator Precedence](http://javascript.crockford.com/tdop/tdop.html)

Two properties of the algorithm make it suit this problem very well:

- The lookup of associativity ("binding power") happens dynamically for each token (allowing the parser to allow the user to define precedence for their operators).
- It's very simple to write by hand[*], and you'll probably have to do that as such an degree of dynamism is beyond the scope of most (at least all I know) parser generators.

[*] I've personally written a parser for a very large (lacking only `case`, multidimensional arrays and perhaps some obscure subtleties) subset of Pascal in 500 lines of Python and 2-3 days of work, the rest is only missing because other parts of the software it's used in were more interesting at the time and I didn't have a reason to implement the rest.